# Maximum likelihood estimator for Bernoulli parameter based on standard normal

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

$X_i \sim Normal(\psi,1), \ \ i = 1, ..., n$

$Y_i = 1$ if $X_i \ge 0.$

$Y_i = 0$ if $X_i < 0.$

Let $\theta = P(Y_i = 1)$.

What is the MLE of $\theta$?

I know how to find the MLE of a Bernoulli success parameter, but I don't know how to do this question.

Comment: Since $P(Y_i=1)=P(X_i\ge 0)=1/2$, I think you did not quote the question correctly. The distribution of $X_i$'s probably depends on $\theta$, in which case $P(Y_i=1)$ would be a function of $\theta$. Then the MLE can be found using the invariance property.

Comment: Yes, it is a test question.  Yes, I did write it correctly.  Yes, I agree that $\theta = 1/2$, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: My guess is that the actual intent of the question is as follows: you don't  know the mean of the Normal distribution, so you don't know $\theta$.   You observe the $x_i$.  What is the MLE of $\theta$?  This could lead to the mistaken answer "the observed fraction of $x_i \geq 0$".  (That's how I would try to answer it, at any rate.)

Comment: Thanks, @jbowman (and @StubbornAtom). Let's assume that you're right, and I will change the expected value of the normal distribution to be unknown. How would you solve it?

Comment: Hint:  The MLE  of a function of the unknown parameters is the function of the MLE of the unknown parameters (the "invariance property").  So, what are the unknown parameters?  What are their MLEs?  What is the function that transforms those parameters to the thing of interest ($P(Y_i=1)$)?

Comment: Maybe it helps to begin by supposing that $\psi = 0$ so that $\theta = P(X_i \ge 0) = P(Y_i = 1) = 0.5.$
In that case, looking at the $Y_i$ as data you will see about half $1$'s and about half $0$'s. What happens to $\theta$ if $\psi < 0?$ If $\psi > 0?$

Comment: @jbowman I need to find the MLE of $\theta$, which I know is $\hat{\theta} = \bar{X}$.  I now need to find a function of $\hat{\theta}$ that equals $\psi$. This is where I'm stuck.  $\psi = P(X_i > 0)$, which is an integral that does not have an analytical solution. Does this mean that $\hat{\psi}$ has to be written as an integral of $\hat{\theta}$?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the integral has an analytic solution; if it did, no-one would ever be able to calculate the CDF of a Normal distribution!

Comment: Even with the update in the question, it remains unclear what is observed and what is unobserved between $X_i$ and $Y_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @jbowman's comments, I think that the solution is this:

$\hat{\psi} = \bar{X}$

$\theta = P(X_i > 0) = P(\frac{X_i - \psi}{1} > \frac{0 - \psi}{1}) = P(Z > -\psi) = 1 - \Phi(-\psi) = \Phi(\psi)$,

where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the standard normal distribution.

By the invariance principle, $\hat{\theta} = \Phi(\hat{\psi}) = \Phi(\bar{X})$

Comment: No... what if $\bar{X} = 5$?  What would you say $P(Y=1)$ is?  Yet your formula would return a very, very small formula.  Also, you need to take into account the fact that the variance of $\bar{X} \neq 1$, due to the sample size.  But you are on the right track.

Comment: I can't control the value of the data.  If the sample mean truly is 5, then $P(Y = 1)$ will be very big.  I don't see anything wrong with that.

The variance as given in the parent normal distribution is 1, so that's why I divided by 1.  Why is this wrong?

Comment: If $\bar{X}=5$, then you have $\theta = \Phi(-5)$, which isn't very big.  2) You're right about the variance, I slightly mis-remembered the problem for a moment.

Comment: Ah - thank you, @jbowman. I wrote $P(Z > -\psi)$, but I interpreted it as $P(Z < \psi)$. I have corrected my solution.  Does it look right now?

Comment: Yes, except you are mixing up your estimated parameters ($\hat{\theta}$) with your actual parameters in your second line: it's $\theta$ that equals $P(X_i > 0)$, and $\hat{\theta}$ is your estimate of that.  Other than that, fine!